# using greater than symbol to compare dates in BQ

Tags: google-bigquery

greater than symbol is used to compare dates, is it correct to use like this or any other solution available?

```
#standardSQL
with table1 as(
select "ProductA" as products, date '2017-1-20' as end_date union all
select "ProductB" as products, date '2017-6-20' as end_date union all
select "ProductC" as products, date '2018-1-20' as end_date union all
select "ProductD" as products, date '2018-6-20' as end_date
)
select products,end_date,if(current_date()>end_date,'outdated','current') status from table1
```

Comment: sure, this works and most likely you already know this by simply running your example and see result. so why you ask  - there should be something that is not visible from your example that drove you to ask your question :o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT products,end_date, if(DATE_SUB(current_date(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)>end_date,'outdated','current') status from table1;
```

Here is another way you can get the same result using the function DATE_SUB. 
There are many different [functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#date_sub) you can use for the [date](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#date-type) data type. The [operator](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#operators) ">" work on many data type including the [date](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#date-type) type.